# How to view SonarQube Unit Test Information

Tags: .net, unit-testing, sonarqube, sonarqube-web, sonarqube-5.4

One of our task requirements is being able to view information regarding Visual Studio unit tests (e.g name of test, duration, etc). However, after running the runner and getting the coverage we noticed that we cannot find a way to view them, and the only indication that there were unit tests were the from the front widget, along with side-bar highlights in the source saying "these blocks were covered".

We found a [post](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-to-manage-unit-tests-and-improve-code-coverage/) on the SonarQube website describing the exact thing we are looking for, and I've [included a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB1hT.png). Since the post was back in 2009, is this feature still available, and how would I access it?

Comment: Have you tried folllowing the instructions in the post you found?  If so, what problems did you encounter?

Comment: @betseyb The post itself looks like they were summarizing the features they made, and the only instructions I found were "1. Download Sonar
2. Unzip Sonar
3. Launch the Sonar web server (sonar.xx start)
4. Launch the Sonar Maven plugin (mvn sonar:sonar)". Even on the sample projects on the official website the only option is viewing the source directly and see which blocks are covered.